# Span dentro de headings h1...h6

Tags: html, html5

É semanticamente incorreto colocar um `span` dentro de um heading?

Ex:

```
<h1>Isso é <span>verdade</span></h1>
```

Comment: [Essa pergunta foi feita no S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524185/can-we-add-a-span-inside-h1-tag)

Comment: Olá Caio, sim eu sei que é possível, mas a pergunta é será que é bom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [norma W3C para os elementos `h1-h6`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) indica que eles podem conter [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) como elementos filhos, o que inclui o [`span`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-span).

Na documentação do [`span`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-span), inclusive, indica que a tag não tem nenhum significado em si (inclusive semântico):

> The `span` element doesn’t mean anything on its own[...]

E ainda pode ser útil quando usado com `class`:

> [...],but can be useful when used together with the Global attributes,
>   e.g., class, lang, or dir.

```css
h1 .verde{
  color: green
}
```

```html
<h1>Isso é <span class="verde">verdade</span></h1>
```

Não há nenhum problema em usar `span` para estilizar ou servir de referência em trechos de elementos tanto *flow* como *phrasing content*. A tag é largamente utilizada para isso.

Comment: Perfeito, era justamente por isso que precisava saber se usar era ou não correto. Obrigado.

Comment: Vc marcou a outra resposta, era isso mesmo? Não tem problema nenhum, mas é que vc só pode marcar 1 resposta como a melhor. Às vezes acontece de usuário novo marcar a outra resposta achando que a que foi marcada anteriormente tb ficará marcada. rs... mas se vc achou a outra resposta melhor, não tem problema.

Comment: Ahh beleza, não sabia, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, totalmente correto!
Por definição da developer.mozilla,  Span é "um conteiner genérico em linha para conteúdo fraseado , que não representa nada por natureza."
Logo, não tem peso semântico, ou seja, não tem problema usar ele em lugar algum. Sendo ele somente usado para fins de estilo.
É importante saber quando usar o `<p></p>` e o `<span></span>`, o `<p></p>` quebra uma linha, ou seja, é "**display: block**", e o `<span></span>` não, ou seja, é "**display: inline**".
Resumindo, se você quiser editar somente uma parte de um texto sem quebrar linha, use o `<span></span>` :)

fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span